# Repack tar.gz to tar and exclude some files

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I have a big backup.tar.gz file (260 GB) and about 160 GB of free storage space.
Backup file contains three big dumb file (old backups, about 190 GB), which is not needed.
So I want to untar backup.tar.gz to pipe excluding some files and tar it back without gzip.
I have a text file, which contain names of dumb files.
So I need something like:
`tar -xz --exclude-from='exclude.lst' -f backup.tar.gz -O - | tar cfv backup.tar -T -`, but it seems not work.

After a first answer, I found a solution here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80239/efficiently-remove-files-from-large-tgz

Comment: It's `-O`, not `-O -`.  And this is fatally flawed: `-O` cats the contents of all the files together, with no metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question belongs on https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

`tar x -O` just concatenates the contents of all the files.  This loses filenames and other metadata, including even where the boundaries between files were.

Use GNU `tar --delete` to rewrite a tar without some of the original members.  Since you have the names of all the files you want to exclude, this should be simple.  Maybe `zcat | tar --delete` to avoid having `tar` recompress the output.

If this answer doesn't steer you in the right direction, I can add more detail tomorrow.

I think I remember seeing an archive swiss-army-knife command-line program that probably had options to do this sort of thing, but a quick search didn't find it.

Comment: Doesn't work on compressed archives.

Comment: @Velkan: That's why my answer suggested `zcat foo.tar.gz | tar --delete`, so tar would see an uncompressed tar archive.  You'd then of course pipe that output output through `zstd` or `xz` or some other compressor that's not obsolete in 2022 to make a new compressed archive.